# cannot read property of null (googlemaps) - even though I make sure page is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a script for google maps which renders me a map on predetermined coords, uses info in the marker array from the search to render infoboxes with current users information etc., but I have a weird problem. The map works fine MOST of the time, but too often (last two days especially.) I´ve gotten the error: "cannot read property of null". As far as I understand from reading other threads, the problem could be that the div containing the map has not been created before trying to add the map (or getelementbyId), which is why I added the domlistener to make sure the page is loaded. Any idea where the problem might be? Because I´m at a loss now :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode($markers); ?>;

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?= $search->area_coords; ?> );

    var mapOptions = {
        center:myLatLng,
        zoom:12,
        maxZoom:14,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

    // Custom MarkerImage - To be designed
    // var markerImage = 'images/markerImage.png';

    var iconBase = 'http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/H/0099FF/';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth:150
    });

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        // Array to contain all the markers for clickevents etc.
        var markersArray = [];
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i]['lat'], markers[i]['long']);
        var contentString = '<div class="marker_info"><div class="float_left"><img height="40" width="40" src="' + markers[i]['picture'] + '"></div>' +
                '<div><a href="profile.php?userid=' + markers[i]['id'] + '">' + markers[i]['title'] +
                '</a></div><br><em>' + markers[i]['price'] + ' pounds</em></div>';

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:position,
            map:map,
            icon:iconBase,
            htmlCode:contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.htmlCode);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

The error message gives me line number 246, which if it checks it correctly should refer to:

```
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?= $search->area_coords; ?> );
```

- but I´m not 100% on this since the browser might read the document differently, or am I wrong here ?

The map_canvas div is created around line 100 as standard as can be (I cant get the HTML to show here but it´s just any normal div):

```
 <div class="map" id="map_canvas">
    <!-- DIV that contains the Map of users -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on where that error is happening? the console should have a line, if it is detected on your code it is a lot easier to debug.

Comment: Where is the html that contains `map_canvas.`